# udev iw add interface rename issue

Tags: systemd, rename, udev, iw

I need to put wifi interface into additional monitor state.

- If I don't use udev rule and wifi interface named by kernel as **wlan0** (default):

> $ iw dev **wlan0** interface add **mon0** type monitor

in this case I don't have any problem and everything works. I can see **mon0** interface in iwconfig output.

```
mon0      IEEE 802.11  Mode:Monitor  Frequency:2.412 GHz  
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
```

- If I'm using udev rule and wifi interface named as **wbrd0**:

70-wireless.rule file:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{address}=="xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx", NAME="wbrd0"
```

> $ iw dev **wbrd0** interface add **mon0** type monitor

In this case iwconfig output looks like this:

```
rename4   IEEE 802.11  Mode:Monitor  Frequency:2.412 GHz  
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

wbrd0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
```

As you can see there's no **mon0** interface and instead it's renamed as **rename4**. I think it's because of udev rule, udev is trying to name new monitor interface as **wbrd0** instead of **mon0**. Probably there's something I'm missing in udev documentation. Though I know that it works with default udev rules but I cannot find a place where it is.

I have a workaround, I can just rename **rename4** interface with:

> $ ip link set **rename4** name **mon0**

But it's really dirty there should be a better way.

So my question is how to write udev rule which will create a monitor interface from existing **wbrd0**?

**OR**

How to find a place in default udev rule which is renaming monitor interface into **mon0** when I'm not using my 70-wireless.rule?